# How to get the time on a datetime column in vb.net on data reader

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Could you help me point out what causing the error on my code? What i would like to achieved is to seperate the date and time in my date time column in the database (PT_TimeIn)

```
sDate = reader.GetDateTime("PT_TimeIn").ToShortDateString
sTime = reader.GetDateTime("PT_TimeIn").ToShortTimeString
```

The error is:

> Conversion to string PT_TimeIn to type integer is not valid

Comment: "Conversion to string PT_TimeIn to type integer is not valid

Answer (score 1):

The `IDataRecord` interface (which is one of the interfaces that the base `DbDataReader` class implements) only provides method `Function GetDateTime(i As Integer) As Date`. Its single parameter is an integer that specifies the field index. There is no overload of `GetDateTime` in `IDataRecord` that takes a string argument for the field name.

You could use `IDataRecord`'s method `Function GetOrdinal(name As String) As Integer` to get the index of the field and pass that to the `GetDateTime` method. Something like this:

```vb
sDate = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("PT_TimeIn")).ToShortDateString
sTime = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("PT_TimeIn")).ToShortTimeString
```

Hope this helps.